# How can one prove that a set of eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues is linearly independent using exponentiation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

More specifically, let $\{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{k}$ be a set of eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_{j}\}_{j=1}^{k}$ and linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{V})$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is a vector space. Show that $\{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{k}$ is linearly independent using the fact that for any eigenvector $v_{j}$ and integer $l, \ T^{l}v_{j} = \lambda_{j}^{l}v_{j}$.

I figured out a way to prove the result with proof by contradiction and some basic properties of linear operators and eigenvectors. But it didn't use the exponentiation method as requested, so the emphasis of my question is how to use the last part: $T^{l}v_{j} = \lambda_{j}^{l}v_{j}$. I'm just not grasping the connection between this relation and the theorem. Is there some deep meaning behind the connection that I'm not seeing? Or is it more of a clever manipulation trick? Thanks for the help.